# Javascript onload functions not being invoked when view returned from Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following POST handler in Spring boot:

```
@PostMapping("/handlePostRequest")
public ModelAndView handlePostRequest(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody ApiRequest apiRequest) {

    // ... Do some stuff with POST params ...

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("myview);
    mav.addObject("myProperty", myProperty);
    return mav;
}
```

However, when it displays my very simple view, the Javascript onload function is never triggered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body onload="alert('hey');">
  <p>hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I can see the "hello" line but the Javascript doesn't work.

Interestingly, if I do a GetMapping for the Spring method (using URL params instead of POST data), the Javascript does work! Anyone know why this is? Why would a POST vs. GET in the controller affect whether the Javascript loads or not? How can I force it to load? I really don't want to have to use a GET here.

UPDATE: Wanted to note that the POST method is being invoked by an ajax call via Javascript. That could make a difference.

Comment: What's being output in your browser?

Comment: With the POST mapping, just "hello". With the GET mapping, "hello" with the "hey" alert.

Comment: Right Click "View => Source", and view the raw HTML that's being output to the browser.

Comment: When I do View Source it's the HTML from the page that generates the POST call. So it seems to not fully redirect the page (plus the URL doesn't change).

Comment: What browser are you using? Use chrome, and check the actual output in the network tab (F12).